# $routeProvider and resolve : more complex factory passed as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Please check [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dz4K9ElK6cW22ABV0M6E)

What I'm doing is I have following AngularJS module:

```
var synergy_module = angular.module('synergy', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($provide, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      template: '<div>{{here}}</div>',
      controller: SpecificationCtrl,
      resolve: {
        w: "myFct"
      }
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
  });

synergy_module.factory("myFct", ["$http",
  function($http) {
    return $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk");
  }
]).factory("my.Fct", ["$http",
  function($http) {
    var o = {
      getWeather: function() {
        return $http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk");
      }
    }
    return o;
  }
])

function SpecificationCtrl($scope, w) {
  $scope.here = w.data;
}
```

This works fine as the `myFct` factory has a simple name and returns `$promise` but it is not very useful. My factories look more like `my.Fct`:

- they have dots in names (aka "packages") and
- return object with methods (these methods return `$promise`)

How can I pass this "complex" `my.Fct` factory to the resolve as a string and specify which method of the factory should be used when resolving?

**Update:**
OK, based on some more search, this works for me:

```
resolve: {w:  ["my.Fct",function (myFct) {
  return myFct.getWeather();
}]}
```

But it is much more code, using the string seems more readable to me...

Comment: Why don't you use a function instead of a string ?

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to use string because it is imho much more readable and takes less code to use it.